# RVM global gemset confusion

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm using a **gemset per project** approach. Suppose I just installed RVM, created a gemset, called 'test' and install rails 3.1.0.rc4 there, which installs a bunch of gems. Now I switch to the global gemset (`rvm gemset use global`), and view my gems. I expect to see empty list, because I didn't install any gems into **global** gemset, but see all my gems from 'test' gemset. How is that?

My guess is that `rvm gem list` show all gems from all gemsets when invoked from global gemset. If so, how can I view only current gemset's gems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In common:

```
rvm <ruby version>@<gemset name> do gem list
```

For example:

```
rvm @test do gem list
```

show that you want: gems on test gemset environment

Another way:

```
rvm use @test
gem list
```

show the same

Answer (score 2):

Use `gem list` instead of `rvm gem list`

Answer (score 1):

in RVM **1.16.0** the command `gem` is removed, it was causing to much confusion and was deprecated a year ago.

instead use:

```
rvm [<ruby>[@<gemset>],...|default|all] [--verbose] do <command> ...
```